# Adding icon to rails application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How can I add an icon to my Rails application (to show in tabs when opened in a browser, etc.)?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use [Favicon Rails](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag) helper:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag %>
```

Or if you want another image than favicon.ico

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'another_image.ico' %>
```

Comment: Simple, but great 'as the rails way' answer.

Comment: I'd just like to add that the favicon.ico file should go in the `public` directory and documentation can be found here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag

Comment: You have to reload the page skipping the cache. `Cmd+Shift+R` or `Ctrl+Shift+R` to view the effect.

Comment: **NOTE** Place the favicon.ico image in `/app/assets/images/` if you are using the asset pipeline, and in `/public/images/` if you are not.

Comment: @Chris.Zou, thanks for the tip! 
I have been struggling to find out why my icon didn't show up until I saw your comment

Answer (score 35):

You're talking about a `favicon`.

Add this in the `head` part of your layout:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/path_to_your_pic"/>
```

Answer (score 11):

Just so people know, the "document root" where you place your favicon.ico is the "public" folder.  As a Rails newb I thought it would be in the root of the entire application.

Also, you may have to clear your cache for it show up.

Answer (score 9):

After reading and trying all this answers without success I ended up doing this

1. Add a file **favicon.png** to your **public/assets** folder
2. In your **$/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** modify the content of the `<head>` tag adding this `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/favicon.png">`

No need to change the web_server configuration file (nginx, apache, etc) no need to precompile the assets.

Just stop and run/debug your web site, clear the cache from your browser and reopen the page. It should work

Answer (score 4):

Put the `favicon.ico` under your `public/` folder and then add `<%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico' %>` to your `<head></head>`

Then if you try it and doesn't work out, even after you cleaning browser's cache, you should try run the server at a different port. By default, rails runs the server at port 3000.

Try changing the port to something you haven’t used before – run the app as:

RAILS 3: rails server -p 12345

RAILS 1/2: ruby script/server -p 12345