# Rails 3.2 (w/ twitter-bootstrap-rails): favicon.ico only shows on default page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, favicon

I have the following on my `application.html`. haml file...

```
= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico', :rel => 'shortcut icon'
```

So, this `.ico` shows up on the Google Chrome tab on the default page (0.0.0.3000) of my web application but not in a sub page (0.0.0.0000/calapps).

This is really strange because when I go on Chrome developer tools I see the following line of HTML under the head tag.

```
<link href=​"/​assets/​favicon.ico" rel=​"shortcut icon" type=​"image/​vnd.microsoft.icon">​
```

You click on the href (hypertext reference) and the 32x32 icon shows up.

---

Update:

I've created a heroku that represents my application [here](http://calapps3.herokuapp.com/calapps).

Strangely, now the favicon doesn't even show up but http://calapps3.herokuapp.com/assets/favicon.ico exists. I have followed all the steps from the article "[How to add favicon in rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901910/how-to-add-favicon-in-rails-3-2)" so I am confused as why this isn't working. Perhaps it is because I only added the favicon_link_tag in application.html.haml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can verify that the favicon is working on every page of your app in my browser (latest Firefox on Windows and Ubuntu). Have you tried clearing your cache and reloading the page (or forcing a reload without cache by pressing ctrl+F5 (for Firefox))?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome...I think it was definitely a cache problem. It seems to be working...Thanks!