# Rails 4: favicon not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, favicon

My favicon just won't show, in Chrome or Firefox. This is how I am rendering it in the `<head>` section:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

It is located in `public/images`.

This is the produced HTML:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
```

Opening the link in my browser shows the icon correctly.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or it just doesn't show up?

Comment: well in the console while the server is running I don't see any icon resource being "get"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The favicon is not handled by the asset pipeline when its in the public folder, and this can cause caching problems.

See here: [How to add favicon in rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901910/how-to-add-favicon-in-rails-3-2) and [Clear the cache from the Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004365/clear-the-cache-from-the-rails-asset-pipeline).

Use the [favicon_link_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag) and place the .ico file in `/app/assets/images/` to get it into the asset pipeline.

If it still doesn't work after that, try clearing your browser cache, your rails cache, and restarting your rails server.

Comment: placing the icon in `assets/images` is the answer