# HTTP Caching images (favicon) in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, http-caching

I’m having trouble configuring Rails 4 to cache an image. I’m trying it out with the favicon, which may be a trivial case in terms of actual performance gain, but I would like to understand this aspect regardless.

I have been simply placing the favicon in my `public` folder and serving it that way. I’m trying instead now to serve it via a simple controller so that I can use the `expires_in` method in ActionController (described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet.html#method-i-expires_in)).

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def favicon
    expires_in 30.minutes, :public => true
    send_file Rails.root.join('public/', 'images/', 'favicon.ico'), type: 'image/x-icon', disposition: 'inline'
  end
end
```

But no dice. When I request the image, here is what I see in my web inspector -

[image]

So as you can see, it is not being cached. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe catch is in cache configuration.
In `/config/development.rb` or `/config/production.rb`:

```
# ...
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
# ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that too. Unfortunately that is not it, I have had that enabled all along

Comment: Check out this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686624/rails-4-favicon-not-showing)