# How do your link to a favicon in ruby on rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, favicon

Here is what I am trying.

`<%= image_tag 'favicon.ico', rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" %>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add favicon in rails 3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901910/how-to-add-favicon-in-rails-3-2)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try add

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

in `head` section in your `application.html.erb`

Comment: Thanks so much!! This was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

How about using `favicon_link_tag` helper method instead?

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```