# My favicon icon is not working in rails site

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml, favicon

OK I am trying to get my favicon working on my site: Hidden for privacy
For some reason it isn't showing. I am using haml and have this in my header...

```
= favicon_link_tag "favicon.ico"
```

It is also producing the html...

```
<link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
```

I do have a favicon.ico in my assets and I am not seeing any issues in my console. Also when I check the source and click the link for the file, it does find it. I have checked every tutorial possible and it doesn't work. I have also tried Safari, Chrome, and Internet Explorer. Thanks for any help.

Comment: here is mine  `<link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />`

Comment: why not try to use just = favicon_link_tag

Comment: I didn't know I could just use `= favicon_link_tag`. That works better codewise, however it still isn't making the favicon show up.

Comment: SNEH PANDYA that is the same as my html output.

Comment: i think you have misplaces you image path check where your favicon located

Comment: as stated above... "I do have a favicon.ico in my assets and I am not seeing any issues in my console. Also when I check the source and click the link for the file, it does find it."

Comment: Your favicon works for me on Firefox and Opera, but not IE or Chrome.

Comment: that's weird. It doesn't work on IE, Chrome, or Safari. I made it through a website converter. Maybe that one changes the format slightly. I may try another site and upload a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon file needs to be under public/assets and clear the browser cache if it still not showing up.

For more details: [Adding Icon to rails website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130593/adding-icon-to-rails-website)

Comment: else try to run rake assets:precompile

Comment: It is under public/assets and the link tag above will do the same thing and grab it from the public/assets folder.

Comment: It works now. I have no idea what the issue is, but I am giving you the answer because I feel that someone else may have this problem and if they had it in the wrong folder it would be a problem.

Comment: It looks like the cache was cleared by one of your actions. In any case thanks for accepting my answer :-)