# Add a logo beside the title in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add a logo beside my title in the tab bar of my rails app. I've been searching for a while now and none of them work for me (maybe I did the wrong way), so please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I found it for you! Look at this my friend :)! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130593/adding-icon-to-rails-application.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a [`favicon.ico`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

Most browsers automatically scan the root directory for a file named `favicon.ico`, so you don't really need to do anything on your rails code.

Comment: so I can put it anywhere?

Comment: No, it needs to be in your website's root folder. At least if you want it to be picked up automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry but where is that? Do I have to declare that?

Comment: in your public folder. from the root directory of your rails app it is ./public/favicon.ico @Tatamatugas